# Generate readonly field for property with ReSharper

Tags: c#, properties, resharper

Since I didn't find whether is ReSharper capable of generating a private readonly backing field for a property, is there a way how to define custom script that could do that?

Imagine you have a property

```
public Type PropertyName { get; set; }
```

and then you set a cursor on this line, press Alt+Enter and there would be a menu item which transforms the property to

```
private readonly Type propertyName;

public Type PropertyName { get { return propertyName; } }
```

I have found myself in the situation where I would actually use this many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With R#, you can create a [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html). In this case:

1. ReSharper > Templates Explorer
2. Live Templates Tab > New Template (small grid icon)
3. Shorcut: propReadOnly (this will be the shortcut used with intellisense)
4. Description: whatever works for you...
5. Available: in C# 2.0 where type member declaration is allowed
6. Create the template as:

   `private readonly $Type$ $propertyName$;`

   `public $Type$ $PropertyName$ { get { return $propertyName$; } }`

Enclosing text in `$SomeText$` will designate that text as a variable for R# to maninpulate.

In the variable name panel:

```
Name             Value             Editable Occurence
Type             Choose Macro*     #2
PropertyName     Choose Macro*     checkbox is checked
propertyName     (see below)       not editable
                 Macro > - Value of annother variable with the first character in lower case
                         - Select "PropertyName" as the other variable

*Choose Macro is displayed when no macro is selected; this is the default setting
```

Save and you can use the template immediately in Visual Studio by typing the shortcut used, i.e., "propReadOnly"

Comment: For other "Live Template Newbs" like me, make sure to use the up and down arrows in the "variable name panel" so that the Parameters are in the order shown. "Type" at the top, followed by "PropertyName", followed by "propertyName".  Thanks @metro!

Answer (score 2):

You could work the other way around with `ReSharper`.

Create your private readonly backing field:

```
private readonly Type propertyName;
```

Then press `alt + insert` to generate the property.

Also see: [Generating Properties](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Code_Generation__Properties.html)

**Edit:**

Another option is to first create a property like this:

```
public MyProperty PropertyName { get { return propertyField;  } }
```

Then press `alt + enter` with your cursor on the fieldName to create the field. You will then jump to the field and by pressing `alt + enter` again `Resharper` will make it a Constructor parameter. Last but not least you'll now get the option to press `alt + enter` again to make the field readonly.

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But I seldom create a readonly field first and then generate a property later. More often, I create a property and later I find out that a property could be readonly because it is never changed after assigned in a constructor.

Comment: I understand, maybe the edit can help you out in the scenario. But I also understand that their is still a bit of work involved adding the field name.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In the end, I accepted the other answer for it gives me exactly what I want and no work-around. It also answer my question better, because I was asking for a custom script.